# Cmake cannot find library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a library called `Kinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu.so` which I want to link against with cmake. So, in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, I have the line:

```
target_link_libraries(demo ~/Libraries/Kinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu.so)
```

However, during compilation, I receive the error:

```
cannot find -lKinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu
```

This baffles me because I am telling cmake to look for `Kinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu.so`, not for `-lKinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu`. Please could somebody explain what is going on?

In verbose mode, the cmake output gives the following:

```
Linking CXX executable demo
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/demo.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/demo.dir/demo.cpp.o  -o demo  -L/home/karnivaurus/Libraries -rdynamic -lKinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu -Wl,-rpath,/home/karnivaurus/Libraries 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lKinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu
```

Comment: Could you turn on CMake's verbose mode and add the link command line to the question ?

Comment: Yes, I've done that now. It seems to be searching for `-lKinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu` even though I have specified `Kinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu.so`.

Answer (score 0):

The `-l` is just the flag used to tell the compiler to link a library.  Your library name is nonstandard.  The compiler will remove the `-l` and prepend `lib` to the string you use, and look for a file called `libKinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu.so`.

This looks like an issue with the distribution of this API.  You can try working around it by creating a symbolic link from `libKinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu.so` to `Kinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu.so`.

Comment: How about just renaming `Kinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu.so` to `libKinova.API.CommLayerUbuntu.so`?

Comment: Sure, try it.  But the API might include other compiled utilities which rely on the library being present with its current name.  A symlink won't break those.